# Is this any measurable function that the set B is the collection of points that makes f continuous for any Borel set B?

Tags: continuity

I can find that the function f
\begin{align} f(x)= & 1/p & (x=p/q, p/q ~ simple) \\
{ } & 0 & (x ~ is ~ irrational) \end{align} is continuous only on x for x irrational and discontinuous on x for x rational. However, I can't find the measurable function that is discontinuous on irrational x and continuous on rational x. So I raise question whether the measurable function f that is continuous on $B$ exists for any Borel set $B$. If it is not true, what is the condition for $B$ that allows a measurable function f continuous only on $B$ and discontinues on $B^c$?

Comment: The rationals are not a $G_\delta$, so cannot be the set of points of continuity. I think this has appeared a number of times on MSE.